# How to execute a c# code dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I am working on C# 3.5 winforms project.

I want to execute some code dynamically, which is in a string variable.
the code, I want to execute is something like this :

```
(GetSetting("MYSETT1") == 1? "OK" : "Cancel")
```

I want to use methods which are existed in my project and by using them I want to perform some task.

Is it possible dynamically ?

Comment: Make it as method and call it. what is dynamic here?

Comment: just like this code i have hundreds of commands, so to make lots of methods for this is not a very good solution.

Comment: For dynamic code generation, you can use [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) or [Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emit%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or ... but, for your case, I think it's just a configuration settings, you can handle it with xml and some code, If you provide more detail about your problem we can help you better.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri *I want to execute some code ... which i have in a string variable* Please share your insights into marking `System.String`s as methods.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri : Which type of info you need

Comment: e.g I want to know where parameters of your methods like: GetSetting("MYSETT1") == 1 initialized, and what's your usage from "OK" or "Cancel" result, why you don't use GetSetting("MYSETT1") result? and where you store this hundreds methods? why do not put them in code instead of storing somewhere else?

Comment: i want to create menus, where some menus are depended on settings, the setting is a table in my database where we store some values like 0,1,2. "GetSetting" is a function which returns value of given setting "MySett1" is name of setting. consider there is a menu named "My Option" which will be visible when value of MYSETT1 is 1

Comment: I'll assign an idea to each menu item, and will fetch related value from database by menu ID. It's just function, instead of parameter `MYSETT1` call function GetSettings(myMenuItem.ID) which returns true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically compile your code and execute.

This links may be helpful:

[Using the CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Dynamically executing code in .Net](http://west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm)

Comment: how can i use the methods which is in my project with this dynamic code ?

Comment: i have found my solution : in CodeDOM .
to execute methods in class in my project i have to add that assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a "pure" Microsoft solution you should check out Roslyn, once it ships. But until then you might want to take a look at the [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex:

> Flee is an expression parser and evaluator for the .NET framework. It allows you to compute the value of string expressions such as sqrt(a^2 + b^2) at runtime. It uses a custom compiler, strongly-typed expression language, and lightweight codegen to compile expressions directly to IL. This means that expression evaluation is extremely fast and efficient. Try out the demo, which lets you generate images based on expressions, and see for yourself.

If that doesn't fit your bill you should check out the shameless self-promotion of my own project, below.

## [ExpressionEvaluator](https://github.com/taspeotis/ExpressionEvaluator)

> ExpressionEvaluator is a library to help developers evaluate C# and VB .NET expressions. The expressions you need to evaluate are compiled through the .NET Framework's own CodeDOM so nearly all language features are supported. The library can expose remotable objects to the expressions for a scripting-like capability. All expression evaluation is sandboxed.

**Example**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var expressions = new List<string>
                            {
                                "3 * 5",
                                "Log10(50)",
                                "Parameters!Greeting + \" World!\""
                            };

    // An ExpressionMeta contains the expressions and extensions to be compiled.
    var meta = new ExpressionMeta("VisualBasic");

    // Add the expressions to be compiled.
    foreach(var expression in expressions)
        meta.AddExpression(expression);

    // Add the extensions to be compiled.
    var extension = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Greeting", "Hello"}};
    meta.AddExtensionIgnoreAssembly(new Extension("Parameters", extension));

    // Compile the expressions
    using(var evaluator = meta.Compile())
    {
        // Evaluate the expression
        foreach(var expression in expressions)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", evaluator.Evaluate(expression));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
15
1.69897000433602
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Mono team makes it possible via

http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

If you want to use Microsoft's product, you will have to wait for Roslyn,

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

Comment: Whatever is new and shiny does erase all memory of what was before.

Comment: You should say whatever comes from Microsoft erases all memory of what was free and open source. It was NAnt/NDoc/NUnit/NHibernate ... (a very long list), but now what we get from Microsoft is quite limited.