# Dynamic string interpolation with math operations

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have an issue with dynamic string interpolation.

The below one works.

```
FormattableString str= $"XYZ{(dynamicvalue * 58) / 5}ABC";
Console.WriteLine(str);
Output =  XYZ34ABC
```

I wanted to create an extension method to evaluate the expression.
something like.

```
string formula ="XYZ{(dynamicvalue * 58) / 5}ABC";
FormattableString str = $formula ;
```

tried different ways but did not work.

Thanks

Comment: That's not how string interpolation works. The dollar sign needs to be before the opening quote for the compiler to know that the string needs to be interpolated.

Comment: Can you show the full extension method that you tried? Where does `dynamicvalue` come from? Which class are you extending?

Comment: Are you basically trying to convert a string into an interpolated string?

Comment: You will have to write an expression evaluator or use Roslyn dynamic C# APIs. [Here is a simple evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268877/2557128) and you can add variable lookup. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545543/2557128) are some other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I not completely sure, what you want to achieve. You could always use

```
string formula = $"XYZ{(dynamicvalue * 58) / 5}ABC"
```

and have the evaluated string right at hand.

But, if you already have a string, where are the values coming from? If you have it in a string, "(dynamicvalue * 58) / 5" are just characters without any connection to a variable. And if you put it in an extension method, there is no way for the compiler, no less the runtime, to determine, what *dynamicValue*'s value actually is.
If, however, you hand the value over to the extension method, you do something like this:

```
public static string EvaluateString<T,U>(this string, Func<T,U> evaluation, T value)
{
  return String.Format(string, evaluation(value));
}
```

and you call it like

```
string evString = "XYZ{0}ABC".Evaluate(x => x * 58 / 5,dynamicvalue);
```

But I think it is easier to read and less error prune to just use the

```
string formula = $"XYZ{(dynamicvalue * 58) / 5}ABC"
```